# How to get NFS Free Disk Space on Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, nfs, exporter

I'm trying to get in prometheus the status of an NFS server and the free disk space on that server.

The configuration that I have is

Server1:

- docker installed
- container with prometheus/grafana ... etc

Server2:

- nfsd server

I'd like to know the status of nfsd on prometheus (if possible, without the need of installing docker on server2)

Regards,

Astin

LE: ElasticSearch can be used as a source also (not mandatory Prometheus)

Comment: No one with ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [node_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter). It exports nfs and nfsd metrics:

```
nfs Exposes NFS client statistics from /proc/net/rpc/nfs. This is the same information as nfsstat -c.   Linux
nfsd Exposes NFS kernel server statistics from /proc/net/rpc/nfsd. This is the same information as nfsstat -s.  Linux
```

Comment: I knew about it ... and tried multiple times but had some issues.
I just said to try again and it seems now worked. Thanks

Comment: Heisenbugs are the best :)

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason, you cannot install node exporter, you can use [volume_exporter](https://github.com/mnadeem/volume_exporter)

You can add it as side car

```
      - name: volume-exporter
      image:  mnadeem/volume_exporter
      imagePullPolicy: "Always"
      args:
        - --volume-dir=prometheus:/prometheus
      ports:
      - name: metrics-volume
        containerPort: 9888
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /prometheus
        name: prometheus-data
        readOnly: true
```